# Cómo recibir un array de una API - TS

Tags: array, reactjs, typescript, api

Hola estoy haciendo una pequeña página del clima para practicar y en la API que uso recibo un array con las predicciones.

Actualmente estoy usando TS y React para practicar también. No tengo ningún problema al recibir la API, sólo que cuando recibo la respuesta de la API debo hacer el setter de cada predicción en la interfaz de la siguiente forma.

```
    interface IForecast {
      date: string;
      icon: string;
      maxC: string;
      minC: string;
    }
    
    const [forecasts, setForecasts] = useState<IForecast[]>([]);
    
function fetchAPI(){
    let forecast0 = {
          date: responseJSON.forecast.forecastday[0].date,
          icon: responseJSON.forecast.forecastday[0].day.condition.icon,
          maxC: responseJSON.forecast.forecastday[0].day.maxtemp_c,
          minC: responseJSON.forecast.forecastday[0].day.mintemp_c,
        };
    
        let forecast1 = {
          date: responseJSON.forecast.forecastday[1].date,
          icon: responseJSON.forecast.forecastday[1].day.condition.icon,
          maxC: responseJSON.forecast.forecastday[1].day.maxtemp_c,
          minC: responseJSON.forecast.forecastday[1].day.mintemp_c,
        };
        let forecast2 = {
          date: responseJSON.forecast.forecastday[2].date,
          icon: responseJSON.forecast.forecastday[2].day.condition.icon,
          maxC: responseJSON.forecast.forecastday[2].day.maxtemp_c,
          minC: responseJSON.forecast.forecastday[2].day.mintemp_c,
        };
        setForecasts([forecast0, forecast1, forecast2]);
}
```

La cuestión es que ir seteando uno por uno cada prediccón no me parece la forma correcta, pues quizás en un futuro necesite que sean 100 predicciones (o 100 de otra cosa cualquiera) y setear cada objeto con la interfaz a mano sería inviable.

Gracias por su tiempo.

Esta es la respuesta de la llamada (en mi codigo sería ResponseJSON)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Puedes explicar o colocar de dónde sale `responseJSON`? Pienso que con un for o algo por el estilo sería más que suficiente.

Comment: @ricardo-dlc Hola, ya actualicé la pregunta con la respuesta de la API que es el ResponseJSON. La parte de forecastDay es la que quiero iterar de alguna forma y no ir haciendo setter de uno a uno por elemento.

Comment: Me refería más bien a en el código, cuándo es que obtienes el valor de `responseJSON` ya que dentro de la función `fetchAPI()` la usas pero ¿de dónde salió? Aunque creo que en este punto tal vez podría ser irrelevante pues con lo que ya proporcionas debería ser suficiente. Ahora mismo no me encuentro en la computadora pero creo que [esta pregunta en el sitio en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53669064/mapping-array-of-object-values-to-interface-type-in-typescript) debería resolver tu problema fácilmente, dale una revisada y si tienes algún problema házlo saber.

Comment: @ricardo-dlc ahhh se me olvidó mencionar que fetchAPI() tiene más código sólo que extraje el pedazo en donde tengo la situación. responseJSON sólo es la el json de la respuesta de la API que utilizo. Que es lo que mostré en la imagen. Intenté hacer lo del link pero no me funcionó.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existen varias formas de hacerlo, todo depende cuál sea más cómoda y/o legible para ti, por ejemplo:

### Declarar el tipo de la variable forecast

La más sencilla desde mi punto de vista, solo tienes que asegurarte de hacer el mapeo de forma correcta dentro del `.map()`.

```js
let forecast: IForecast[] = responseJSON.forecast.forecastday.map(f => ({date: f.date, icon: f.day.condition.icon, maxC: f.day.maxtemp_c, minC: f.day.mintemp_c}));
```

### Usar una afirmación de tipo al retorno de la función

TypeScript ofrece un mecanismo para poder utilizar información sobre el tipo de un valor que no conoce utilizando *[type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions)*. Con esto le estás diciendo a TypeScript que utilice el tipo que especificas en lugar del tipo que trata de inferir.

```js
let forecast = responseJSON.forecast.forecastday.map(f => ({date: f.date, icon: f.day.condition.icon, maxC: f.day.maxtemp_c, minC: f.day.mintemp_c} as IForecast));
```

### Inferencia en la función

Una forma similar a la anterior podría lograrse sin en lugar de utilizar esta afirmación al retorno de la función, la utilizas en la función (la respuesta la tenías en tu código, en `useState<IForecast[]>()`, la única diferencia es que no declarabas que fuera un array, solo el tipo) para ayudar a TypeScript con la [inferencia](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) y con esto dar con el tipo correcto.

```js
let forecast = responseJSON.forecast.forecastday.map<IForecast>(f => ({date: f.date, icon: f.day.condition.icon, maxC: f.day.maxtemp_c, minC: f.day.mintemp_c}));
```

En este caso, la inferencia se hace "fuera" de la función `.map()`.

Puedes probar las tres opciones en este [playground](https://tsplay.dev/wgLKbN).

---

Tu código al final sería algo como lo siguiente (dependiendo del tipo de inferencia que hayas utilizado):

```js
interface IForecast {
  date: string;
  icon: string;
  maxC: string;
  minC: string;
}

const [forecasts, setForecasts] = useState<IForecast[]>([]);

function fetchAPI(){
  let forecast: IForecast[] = responseJSON.forecast.forecastday.map(f => ({date: f.date, icon: f.day.condition.icon, maxC: f.day.maxtemp_c, minC: f.day.mintemp_c}));

   setForecasts(forecast);
}
```

Comment: Gracias, justo eso necesitaba. Aunque e objeto F del map() tuve que ponerle que era de tipo any. Feliz día.

Comment: Genial, si te sirvió esta respuesta considera marcarla como la correcta o en su defecto, coloca tu solución como respuesta y la marcas como correcta, así ayudas a futuros visitantes. Saludos.